# Why does right shift in PHP return a negative number?

Tags: php, ip-address, bitwise-operators

I am trying to query a bittorrent tracker and am using unpack to get the list of IPs from the response. So, something like this:

```
$ip = unpack("N", $peers);
$ip_add = ($ip[1]>>24) . "." . (($ip[1]&0x00FF0000)>>16) . "." . (($ip[1]&0x0000FF00)>>8) . "." . ($ip[1]&0x000000FF);
```

But, for some reason, I am getting the following IP addresses when I print $ip_add:

```
117.254.136.66
121.219.20.250
-43.7.52.163
```

Does anyone know what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use [long2ip()](http://php.net/long2ip) to transform number back into ip

Comment: You are a savior! Thanks a lot. Cannot accept as answer within 10 mins of posting :)In any case, could you tell me what was going wrong with my method?

Comment: you have to add 2^31 to $ip before calculations ($ip + pow(2, 31))

Answer (score 5):

As zerkms says, `long2ip` does what you want. To answer your question, [`>>`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php) is an [arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift) right shift (so named because `$i >> $j` is equivalent to the arithmetic expression `i / 2j`), which propagates the sign bit to preserve the sign of the number. That is, `$i < 0` [iff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_and_only_if) `($i >> $j) < 0`. PHP doesn't have a [logical shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_shift) (but you could [define your own](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642026/php-equivalent-javascript-shift-right-with-zero-fill-bitwise-operators)).

Comment: I see... Understood. Thanks for the explanation. Will go through the info you've provided. +1 Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function decode_ip($str){
    $str = (float)($str);
    $ip = array(
        (int)($str/pow(2,24)),
        (int)($str/pow(2,16) & 0xFF),
        (int)($str/pow(2,8) & 0xFF),
        (int)($str & 0xFF)
    );
    return join(".", $ip);
}
```

`decode_ip("3225422716"); //192.64.11.124`