# Javascript ">>>" to PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to convert this Javascript to PHP but i got struck with ">>>".
Any idea to convert it?

`_loc7 = (_loc2 >>> 5 ^ _loc3 << 2) + (_loc3 >>> 3 ^ _loc2 << 4) ^ (_loc6 ^ _loc3) + (_loc9[_loc1 & 3 ^ _loc8] ^ _loc2);`

P/s: Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Are you sure this code works ? This operator is not listed [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_operators.asp) and I cannot find any page mentioning it with my search engine. (unlike [<<<](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700042/in-php-what-does-represent))

Comment: Gabriel Devillers Yes. ">>>" mean "Zero-fill right shift" in 
Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is fixed in [Unsigned Right Shift / Zero-fill Right Shift / >>> in PHP (Java/JavaScript equivalent)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41134337/unsigned-right-shift-zero-fill-right-shift-in-php-java-javascript-equiv/43359819#43359819)

Topic closed. Thanks for helping me.